# How to set the timeout for a TcpClient?

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, tcpclient

I have a TcpClient which I use to send data to a listener on a remote computer. The remote computer will sometimes be on and sometimes off. Because of this, the TcpClient will fail to connect often. I want the TcpClient to timeout after one second, so it doesn't take much time when it can't connect to the remote computer. Currently, I use this code for the TcpClient:

```
try
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("remotehost", this.Port);
    client.SendTimeout = 1000;

    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(this.Message);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    data = new Byte[512];
    Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    this.Response = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

    stream.Close();
    client.Close();    

    FireSentEvent();  //Notifies of success
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    FireFailedEvent(ex); //Notifies of failure
}
```

This works well enough for handling the task. It sends it if it can, and catches the exception if it can't connect to the remote computer. However, when it can't connect, it takes ten to fifteen seconds to throw the exception. I need it to time out in around one second? How would I change the time out time?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You would need to use the async [`BeginConnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xw3y33he.aspx) method of `TcpClient` instead of attempting to connect synchronously, which is what the constructor does. Something like this:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
var result = client.BeginConnect("remotehost", this.Port, null, null);

var success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

if (!success)
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to connect.");
}

// we have connected
client.EndConnect(result);
```

Comment: what's the point of using asynchronous connect, and "synchronize" it back with Wait?
I mean, i currently trying to understand how to implement timeout with asynchronous read, but the solution is not by completely disable the asynchronous design.
should use socket timeouts or cancellation token or something like that.
otherwise, just use connect/read instead...

Comment: @RoeeK: The point is what the question says: to programmatically select an arbitrary timeout for the connection attempt. This is not an example on how to do async IO.

Comment: @RoeeK: The whole point of this question is that `TcpClient` does not offer a sync connect function with a configurable timeout, which is one of your proposed solutions. This is a workaround to enable it. I'm not sure what else to say without repeating myself.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I've probably seen too many "WaitOnes" on async operations where it's really not needed..

Comment: I've upvoted this answer but the code is not foolproof. It assumes that if the WaitOne operation succeeds then "we're connected" but that's not the case. The WaitOne operation can, indeed, return before the timeout but the socket connection failed. If you unplug your network cable, you'll get connection errors almost immediately and the timeout will never occur. The SocketException will the thrown when EndConnect is called.

Comment: This code will leak resources (specifically, wait handles) if the connection cannot be made, since `EndConnect` is never called. This may be a price you're willing to pay if you expect connection problems to be infrequent, but it's worth keeping mind.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for pointing this out, but let's keep in mind this is not production-grade code. People, please don't copy paste code that comes with the comment "something like this" in your production system. =)

Answer (score 124):

Starting with .NET 4.5, TcpClient has a cool [ConnectAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138320.aspx) method that we can use like this, so it's now pretty easy:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
if (!client.ConnectAsync("remotehost", remotePort).Wait(1000))
{
    // connection failure
}
```

Comment: Additional benefit in ConnectAsync is that Task.Wait can accept a CancellationToken to stop immediately in case of need even before the timeout.

Comment: .Wait will synchronously block, removing any benefit of the "Async" portion.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43237063/613620 is a better fully asynchronous implementation.

Comment: @TimP. where have you seen the word "async" in the question?

Comment: I think it is a good answer, I would however return 
return client.Connected; 
My test cases shown that waiting alone is not enough for a definitive answer

Comment: You just reduced my response time for 10 clients from 28 seconds to 1.5 seconds!!! Awesome!

Comment: It's now possible to use "WaitAsync()" instead to keep the connection async.

Answer (score 23):

Another alternative using https://stackoverflow.com/a/25684549/3975786:

```
var timeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);     
var cancellationCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
try
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeOut))
    {
        using (var client = new TcpClient())
        {
            var task = client.ConnectAsync(hostUri, portNumber);

            using (cts.Token.Register(() => cancellationCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true)))
            {
                if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, cancellationCompletionSource.Task))
                {
                    throw new OperationCanceledException(cts.Token);
                }
            }

            ...

        }
    }
}
catch(OperationCanceledException)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the correct fully asynchronous implementation.

Comment: Why is it not possible to use a `Task.Delay` to create a task that completes after a certain time instead of using the `CancellationTokenSource/TaskCompletionSource` for providing the delay? (I tried and it locks, but I don't understand why)

Comment: When is task canceled? Sure this unblocks the called after the time out but isn't ConnectAsync() still running on the thread pool somewhere?

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer to @MondKin 's question too

Comment: To answer the question (albeit a bit late), using a simple `Task.Run(()=>Task.Delay(5))` prevents disposing of the delay `Task` if the actual operation completes prior to the delay in the `WhenAny` call, and not disposing of the task leaks the async handle. You can cancel the delay prior to disposal using the overload, but then you need a `CancellationToken` anyway so you're not saving anything (in fact cancelling the Delay adds more LoC than this solution)

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: Seems to deadlock in .NET 6

Answer (score 12):

The answers above don't cover how to cleanly deal with a connection that has timed out. Calling TcpClient.EndConnect, closing a connection that succeeds but after the timeout, and disposing of the TcpClient.

It may be overkill but this works for me.

```
    private class State
    {
        public TcpClient Client { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; }
    }

    public TcpClient Connect(string hostName, int port, int timeout)
    {
        var client = new TcpClient();

        //when the connection completes before the timeout it will cause a race
        //we want EndConnect to always treat the connection as successful if it wins
        var state = new State { Client = client, Success = true };

        IAsyncResult ar = client.BeginConnect(hostName, port, EndConnect, state);
        state.Success = ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout, false);

        if (!state.Success || !client.Connected)
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect.");

        return client;
    }

    void EndConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var state = (State)ar.AsyncState;
        TcpClient client = state.Client;

        try
        {
            client.EndConnect(ar);
        }
        catch { }

        if (client.Connected && state.Success)
            return;

        client.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated code. Is it possible to get the SocketException thrown if the connect call fails before timeout?

Comment: It already should. The WaitOne will release when either the Connect call completes (successfully or otherwise) or the timeout elapses, whichever happens first.  The check for !client.Connected will raise the exception if the connect "failed fast".

Answer (score 9):

One thing to take note of is that it is possible for the BeginConnect call to fail before the timeout expires.  This may happen if you are attempting a local connection.   Here's a modified version of Jon's code...

```
        var client = new TcpClient();
        var result = client.BeginConnect("remotehost", Port, null, null);

        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        if (!client.Connected)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect.");
        }

        // we have connected
        client.EndConnect(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code improvement based on [mcandal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43237063) solution. 
Added exception catching for any exception generated from the `client.ConnectAsync` task (e.g: SocketException when server is unreachable)

```
var timeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);     
var cancellationCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

try
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeOut))
    {
        using (var client = new TcpClient())
        {
            var task = client.ConnectAsync(hostUri, portNumber);

            using (cts.Token.Register(() => cancellationCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true)))
            {
                if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, cancellationCompletionSource.Task))
                {
                    throw new OperationCanceledException(cts.Token);
                }

                // throw exception inside 'task' (if any)
                if (task.Exception?.InnerException != null)
                {
                    throw task.Exception.InnerException;
                }
            }

            ...

        }
    }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException operationCanceledEx)
{
    // connection timeout
    ...
}
catch (SocketException socketEx)
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If using async & await and desire to use a time out without blocking, then an alternative and simpler approach from the answer provide by mcandal is to execute the connect on a background thread and await the result. For example:

```
Task<bool> t = Task.Run(() => client.ConnectAsync(ipAddr, port).Wait(1000));
await t;
if (!t.Result)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Connect timed out");
   return; // Set/return an error code or throw here.
}
// Successful Connection - if we get to here.
```

See the [Task.Wait MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) for more info and other examples.

Answer (score 2):

As **[Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30917334/5113030)** mentioned, it's possible to use `ConnectAsync` TcpClient's method with `Task` in addition and stop operation as soon as possible.
For example:

```
// ...
client = new TcpClient(); // Initialization of TcpClient
CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken(); // Required for "*.Task()" method
if (client.ConnectAsync(this.ip, this.port).Wait(1000, ct)) // Connect with timeout of 1 second
{

    // ... transfer

    if (client != null) {
        client.Close(); // Close the connection and dispose a TcpClient object
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // Stop asynchronous operation after successull connection(...and transfer(in needed))
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connetion timed out");
}
// ...
```

Also, I would recommended checking out [AsyncTcpClient](https://github.com/ygoe/AsyncTcpClient) C# library with some examples provided like `Server <> Client`.

Answer (score 2):

Since **.NET 5**, ConnectAsync accepts a cancellation token as additional parameter out-of-the-box [1]. With this, one can simply set up a CancellationTokenSource and hand its token over to the connect method.

Timeout maybe be handled by catching the OperationCanceledException as usual with similar cases (TaskCanceledException). Note that most of the cleanup is accounted for by the using blocks.

```
        const int TIMEOUT_MS = 1000;

        using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                // Create token that will change to "cancelled" after delay
                using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(
                    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TIMEOUT_MS)
                ))
                {
                    await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(
                        address,
                        port,
                        cts.Token
                    );
                }

                // Do something with the successful connection
                // ...
            }

            // Timeout reached
            catch (OperationCanceledException) {
                // Do something in case of a timeout
            }

            // Network-related error
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                // Do something about other communication issues
            }

            // Some argument-related error, disposed object, ...
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Do something about other errors
            }
        }
```

The CancellationTokenSource may be hidden by a small extension method (with tiny extra cost for the additional async/await):

```
public static class TcpClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task ConnectAsync(
        this TcpClient client,
        string host,
        int port,
        TimeSpan timeout
    )
    {
        // Create token that will change to "cancelled" after delay
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(
                host,
                port,
                cts.Token
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connectasync?view=net-6.0

Source Code for ConnectAsync (.NET 6):
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.16/src/libraries/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.Tasks.cs#L85-L126

Answer (score 1):

I am using these generic methods; they can add timeout and cancellation tokens for any async task. Let me know if you see any problem so I can fix it accordingly.

```
public static async Task<T> RunTask<T>(Task<T> task, int timeout = 0, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    await RunTask((Task)task, timeout, cancellationToken);
    return await task;
}

public static async Task RunTask(Task task, int timeout = 0, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (timeout == 0) timeout = -1;

    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken);
    await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask);

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    if (timeoutTask.IsCompleted)
        throw new TimeoutException();

    await task;
}
```

**Usage**

```
await RunTask(tcpClient.ConnectAsync("yourhost.com", 443), timeout: 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**ConnectAsync() with time out and CancellationToken** (.NET 6)
Something a little simpler that worked for my purposes (i.e. checking connectivity).

```
using var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
var connectTask = tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port, cancellationToken);
await connectTask.AsTask().WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken);
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
// Use connected TcpClient here
```