# Is there a way to cancel non-cancellable C# task without waiting the timeout if the task finishes earlier?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, cancellation

I have a method in which I have no control (let's assume it comes from another library):

```
private static void DoWork()
{
    // I have no control over this method
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still working");
    }
}
```

And I want to wait it some time (for example 20 seconds) and if the job isn't finished in this time to stop the code.

What I've tried so far:

- Using Task-cancellation pattern isn't an option for me because I have no control over the method I am executing
- Using only the `Task` class isn't an option because I cannot stop the execution of the task without using cancellation token

  ```
  var taskToWaitAndKill =
      Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork);
  taskToWaitAndKill.Wait(20000); // 20 seconds
  // The task cannot be stopped (aborted) and still runs...
  ```
- Using the `Thread` class, waiting it and aborting it it is not an option because I need to wait all of the 20 seconds before stopping the code.

  ```
  var thread = new Thread(DoWork);
  thread.Start();
  Thread.Sleep(20000);
  thread.Abort();
  ```

So my question **is there a way in C# to wait fixed number of milliseconds for a code to execute and if the code finishes earlier not to wait any longer?**

Comment: Must you abort the operation? Or can it continue in the background while you resume your work?

Comment: See [if this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25684549/1870803) helps.

Answer (score 2):

> Using the Thread class, waiting it and aborting it it is not an option because I need to wait all of the 20 seconds before stopping the code.

Do it differently and you can do it:

```
var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
var started = DateTime.UtcNow;
var thread = new Thread(DoWork);
thread.Start();
while (thread.IsAlive && DateTime.UtcNow - started < timeout)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    // Do whatever here
}

// timeout occured, aborting
if (thread.IsAlive)
    thread.Abort();
```

However, killing a Thread by `Abort` is a [dangerous operation](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation), might cause surprises. If you really has to execute foreign codes, which you cannot control (eg. 3rd party plugins), then you should create an [`AppDomain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) for them. In case of any errors (including `ThreadAbortException`) you could unload the `AppDomain` securely.