# C# TcpClient Timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, tcpclient, networkstream, socketexception

Im trying to connect to my router inside local network. I've used the TcpClient so far.

**Check my code:**

```
public static void RouterConnect()
        {    
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("192.168.180.1",23); <-- Timeout comes up here
            tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 2000; // Not working
            tcpClient.SendTimeout = 2000; // Also not working
            NetworkStream nStream = tcpClient.GetStream(); <-- thought Timeout would raise here

            // Further code here. But already tested while commented out. 
            // So everything else expect the code above shouldnt be relevant.
        }
```

I would like to add a settings-form (router-ip/user/password). Therefore there could be a fail on the user-side where the user types in a not existing host-ip.

The current timeout is at about **20 seconds** which is way too high. `TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout` and `TcpClient.SendTimeout` arnt the right timeouts to set as I already tried it. Google wasnt helping me out with this.

So, anyone knows how to set the timeout in the right way for this? I've read about async. connections which I wouldnt like to use. A cleaner 1-line-timeout-set would be nice. Possible?

Thanks very much!

**Edit 1:** 
With a closer look while debugging I noticed, the timeout is already raising at the initialization of the tcpClient (as edited above in my code) not as I thought before at `.GetStream()`.

---

**EDIT SOLUTION:**

As no one posted the working code from the solution I picked, here it is how its working:

```
public static void RouterConnect()
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            if(tcpClient.ConnectAsync("192.168.80.1",23).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
            {
                NetworkStream nStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not connect!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where are you reading from the stream?

Comment: It comes later but isnt relevant I guess. I commented out the reading. The timeout comes as seen in my edited code above at the initialization of the tcpClient.

Comment: That constructor of `TcpClient` also [connects the client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56(v=vs.110).aspx) to the endpoint.

Comment: @cubrr Yeah thanks. Just noticed that about 5 minutes before. Anyway, my question stays the same.

Comment: I suppose your question is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118632/how-to-set-the-timeout-for-a-tcpclient). If you're targeting .NET 4.5, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30917334/996081) might do the trick.

Comment: Yeah async. connection. As told above I hoped getting around it. Looks like I have no chance going another way.

Comment: Internally, `WSAConnect` is used to connect the socket. I didn't find anything that would suggest that the socket's connection timeout can be altered.

Comment: As my solution isnt posted below I'll edit (append) my solution into my question and mark the closest answer. Thanks to you guys!

Comment: @cubrr Thanks to you too. Followed your commented answer (4.5...).

Comment: @C4ud3x You can (and should) post your solution as an answer yourself and accept it if it...solved your question :)

Comment: @cubrr Yeah normally yes. But `Or Harambam` went into the right direction with his answer AND come on.. his reputation... thought I would rather go this way and give him his tick mark ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i know is to use the Async methods.
There is a nice new async method in .Net 4.5 which returns a Task that you could Wait like this:

```
tcpClient.ConnectAsync().Wait(timeout)
```

It returns a false if it doesn't succeed.

Comment: Ill check it out. Its quite the same as cubrr noticed in the comments under my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the cleanest way I suppose would be to use the [TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms145193%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).BeginConnect
method.

So you would have a asynchronous feedback whether you could connect to the endpoint or not. 
Also see this:
[Async Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118632/how-to-set-the-timeout-for-a-tcpclient)

Comment: Regarding your Edit: Yeah the onstructor also call connect. As an alternative you could call the empty constructor and then use Connect or BeginConnect

Answer (score 0):

The current constructor overloading method your using is also connecting and thus blocking you until it get connected.

**Furthermore**, There are no properties on `TcpClient` to control the `TcpClient` timeout.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx): `TcpClient(String, Int32)`

> Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and connects to the
>   specified port on the specified host.

**Alternative code from [Social MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2281199d-cd28-4b5c-95dc-5a888a6da30d/tcpclientconnect-timeout?forum=csharpgeneral)**

```
using (vartcp = new TcpClient())  
{  
    IAsyncResult ar = tcp.BeginConnect("192.168.180.1", 23, null, null);  
    System.Threading.WaitHandle wh = ar.AsyncWaitHandle;  
    try 
    {  
       if (!ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))  
       {  
           tcp.Close();  
           throw new TimeoutException();  
       }  

        tcp.EndConnect(ar);  
    }  
    finally 
    {  
        wh.Close();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Looked good in the first step. Unfortunately it stays at 20 seconds.

Comment: Those timeout properties do not affect the `Connect` method.