# System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient slow in powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

```
try
{
  $tcp = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

  $tcp.ReceiveTimeout = 500
  $tcp.SendTimeout = 500

  $tcp.Connect('127.0.0.1',80)
  Write-Host "Connection possible!"
  $tcp.close()
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Cannot connect!"
    $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Measure-Command - 21 seconds (always 21!)

```
If $tcp.Connect('127.0.0.1',80,$Null)
```

Measure-Command - 10 milliseconds

Why?

I know that there should be no $Null param but why is it fast with it ?

Comment: $tcp.Connect take two parameters not three https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7ew360f(v=vs.110).aspx. With  three parameters  raise exception:Cannot connect!
Cannot find an overload for "Connect" and the argument count: "3".  It take 1 second to run with success connection  in my machine with 2 parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that there should be no $Null param but why is it fast with it ?

Because your code is broken.

```
try 
{

}
catch
{
}
```

is catching *every possible error*, and *hiding the error messages*.

Your first code, the error is a genuine TCP connection which timed out after a ~30 second wait, and the connection really has failed.

Your second code, the error is "*Cannot find an overload for Connect which takes 3 parameters*" - but you hide the error and *wrongly* print 'cannot connect' instead. This is misleading you. It's not faster, it's broken.

---

The send and receive timeouts are not for connections, they are timeouts for the methods to sending and receive data. There is no way to change the connection timeout with the `.connect()` method, you need to make an asynchronous connection without your own timeout to do that.

e.g. [How to set the timeout for a TcpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118632/how-to-set-the-timeout-for-a-tcpclient)  and [How to configure socket connect timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062035/how-to-configure-socket-connect-timeout) (both C#, but still .Net and the ideas are applicable to PowerShell).

And this https://superuser.com/questions/805621/test-network-ports-faster-with-powershell which has an answer for PowerShell

Comment: Thanks,  if (!$tcp.ConnectAsync("234234", 80).Wait(500)) {'fail'} solves everything

Answer (score 0):

`$tcp.Connect('127.0.0.1',80,$Null)` throws an exception
`Cannot find an overload for "Connect" and the argument count: "3".` Read more here: [MDSN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbhht5w(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I see it. But why it work fast with $null ? I mean it work fast both ways if port is really OK. If not - only $Null variant works fast

Comment: I don't know. On my computer this code ended after milliseconds

Comment: @IgorKuznetsov Does it succeed or error? I think the point Endorphinex is making is that the code ends fast because it errors out, not that it returns valid results.

Comment: This may take more or less, depending on network card and internet connection speed.

Comment: @JClaspill This bigger code work as intended, but this smaller one throws me an exception

Comment: It is the same on my windows server at work.. Without $Null code took 21 seconds...  Cant see any logic

Comment: Maybe, with `$Null` PS sees it, and immediately throws an exception, but without `$Null` it must wait until it connect to this address...

Comment: Found solution. There should be no quotes near IP address. '127.0.0.1' works 21 seconds.... $tcp.Connect(127.0.0.1,80) works for 7 milliseconds  :))

Comment: Hmm, no, quotes need.. Exception calling "Connect" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null...